# Class template for numeric types

Tags: c++, templates

How do I write a class template that accepts only numeric types (`int`, `double`, `float`, etc.) as template?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Do you also want to fix the title? I'm confused if OP really means types or actually means constants of those types.

Comment: @pmr I didn’t (but I did now), good catch. I’m fairly sure that OP means types, if for no other reason that you cannot use non-integral types as non-type templates, and that the question doesn’t make any sense to begin with when talking about non-type templates.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I mean types.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the [`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) type trait. If you want to only enable instantiation of a class with such a type, use it in conjunction with [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<
    typename T, //real type
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type
> struct S{};

int main() {
   S<int> s; //compiles
   S<char*> s; //doesn't compile
}
```

For a version of `enable_if` that's easier to use, and a free addition of `disable_if`, I highly recommend reading [this wonderful article](http://web.archive.org/web/20170705074036/https://rmf.io/cxx11/almost-static-if) on the matter.

In C++, the technique described above has a name called "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error" (most use the acronym SFINAE). You can read more about this C++ technique on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) or [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

As of C++20, [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) make this much easier and don't spoil the interface:

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept arithmetic = std::integral<T> or std::floating_point<T>;

template<typename T>
  requires arithmetic<T>
struct S{};
// Shorthand: template<arithmetic T> struct S {};
```

Do note that there are many user types meant to be used arithmetically as well, though, so a more general concept that covers the *operations* you're looking for instead of the *types* you're looking for would be preferable in a generic interface.

Comment: You can leave off `typename Dummy =`. Furthermore I highly recommend using [Wheels](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels) here, it makes the code vastly simpler: `template <typename T, wheels:EnableIf<wheels::IsArithmetic<T>>>`

Comment: @KonradRudolph, You're right, thanks. And I'll add a link to his `enable_if` post for further reading.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Removing the `Dummy` is what made it not compile, but I'm not too experienced with it, so I can't say how it's supposed to be, other than that. I realized I could remove the pointless name, though.

Comment: My fault, I forgot the parameter pack. Here’s a running example: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=78592aa7213e78a32094dd8f4c929d2e – Notice the trailing `...` after the `EnableIf`.

Comment: Link is broken. Please fix if possible.

Comment: @Rounaq_intel, Thanks for the heads up. Looks like the site has moved, so I put up the new one. However, I'm currently getting an error from it and the wayback machine isn't helping for either URL, so this is the best I've got.

Comment: hello @chris. What does `typename = ...`  do, can we drop `typename = `?

Comment: @Ethanabc, It's a template parameter with no name and a default argument, similar to `void foo(int = 5);`. We don't need the name here since the parameter exists for the sole purpose of SFINAE. Dropping it completely would try to create a non-type parameter of the specified type (the "returned" type from `enable_if`), which isn't valid, or at least wasn't when I wrote the answer, but concepts are the preferred approach in the current year anyway.

Comment: @chris Thank you for the explanation as well as the `concepts` things.

Comment: NB: There's nothing preventing someone from manually specifying the second type parameter like `S<char*, void>`. It's possible to prevent this with SFINAE with a more verbose construct, but at this point you might as well just move over to concepts.

Comment: @NathanPierson, Fair point, and it's about time this answer mentioned concepts, so I've done that.

Answer (score 28):

I found the error messages received from the `template<typename T, typename = ...>` approach highly cryptic (VS 2015), but found that a `static_assert` with the same type trait also works and lets me specify an error message:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename NumericType>
struct S
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<NumericType>::value, "NumericType must be numeric");
};

template <typename NumericType>
NumericType add_one(NumericType n)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<NumericType>::value, "NumericType must be numeric");
    return n + 1;
}

int main()
{
    S<int> i;
    S<char*> s; //doesn't compile

    add_one(1.f);
    add_one("hi there"); //doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: Sure. It would be nice to add this message here.

Comment: this approach 1. makes the API have one less template parameter... and less parameters seems cleaner and 2. static_assert is easier to understand IMO. yet this solution has much less upvotes. Perhaps the [other approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14294277/52074) is preferred because the function signature explicitly SHOWS what types are supported.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Is the `NumericType` template parameter really less clear/explicit than the dummy `std::enable_if<...>` one?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Nah, the other answer isn't nearly as preferred as it seems. It just had more than three years worth of a head start!

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith do you all work together or something? This is is a surprising amount of action for this old question (though I appreciate the upvotes :) )

Comment: I agree that `static_assert` is a lot more readable. The downside is that it doesn't take part in SFINAE. This means you can't overload `addone` to have a version that only accepts a non arithmetic type. Admittedly in this example that doesn't really make sense. Imagine, however, that you want two different versions of `addone`. One for integers and one for floats. You can't achieve that with `static_assert`. You'd need to use `std::enable_if`.