# Is it possible to force a template function to only accept parameters of a certain numerical type?

Tags: c++

For example

```
template <typename T>
T foo(){ ... }
```

where T can only be a floating point type, that is float / double / long double

Comment: "explicit" constructor?

Comment: related stackoverflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14294267/52074

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type foo() { ... }
```

It's completely standard SFINAE; we enable on the return type. If T is not a floating point type, `std::is_floating_point<T>::value` will be `false` and `std::enable_if<false, T>` does not provide a `type` typedef, which causes the function to not be compilable.

For information on these standard library classes see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with template specialization and SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo_enabled
{
};

template<>
struct foo_enabled<float>
{
    typedef void *value;
};

template<>
struct foo_enabled<double>
{
    typedef void *value;
};

template<>
struct foo_enabled<long double>
{
    typedef void *value;
};

template <typename T>
T foo(typename foo_enabled<double>::value=NULL){ ... }
```

Naturally, if you have C++11, Andrei Tita's solution is smarter.

Comment: Is it my imagination or was that a Markdown bug you found before.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No idea... I copied, pasted, something went wrong. Deleted, copied, pasted again several times and it finally went right. Maybe some invisible character in the margin...

Comment: mm I tried to reproduce briefly on meta and failed; didn't look into it further but it looked interesting for a moment there. Well, fsvo "interesting" anyway ;)