# C++ template for numeric types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to have a template to select on numeric types, but I want to also have a global type template too. I tried to apply the solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294267/class-template-for-numeric-types) question, but it didn't work:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Types>
void myFct(T arg1, Types ... rest) { /*do stuff*/ }

template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type, 
                     typename ... Types>
void myFct(T arg1, Types ... rest) { /* do stuff */ }
```

because now I have two functions with the same header. What's the right way to do something like:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Types>
void myFct(T arg1, Types ... rest) 
{ 
    if (isNumeric(T))
        doNumericStuff();
    else
        doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried inverting the condition for enable_if and slapping it into the first template (the one for general purpose Ts)? Its worse solution than tag dispatch, but its a solution.

Comment: Yeah I tryed, i got error code C2995 function template has already been defined, cause `myFct(T, Types)` have 2 definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's probably better ways of doing this, but the simplest way to me is to just slap the `enable_if` onto the return type:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Types>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_arithmetic<T>::value
>::type
myFct(T arg1, Types ... rest) { /*do numeric stuff*/ }

template<typename T, typename ... Types>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_arithmetic<T>::value
>::type
myFct(T arg1, Types ... rest) { /*do non-numeric stuff*/ }
```

This gets very unwieldy once you have more than just two mutually exclusive options, but this will definitely work.

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I want. I am just not sure how the typename as the return type works... Will go check this.

Answer (score 5):

Update for C++17

`if constexpr` discards the unused branch so this is easier ([live link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8cdseB5XnK9qL7g6)):

```
void myFct() { }

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void myFct(T arg1, Ts... rest) {
    if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<T>{}) {
        std::cout << "squared: " << arg1*arg1 << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "not-number\n";
    }
    myFct(rest...); // recurse
}
```

---

You can use tag-dispatching here, and overload the implementation function, since your "do stuff" only seems to be concerned with one object at a time.

```
template <typename T>
void do_stuff(T arg, std::true_type) {
  std::cout << "number\n";
}

template <typename T>
void do_stuff(T arg, std::false_type) {
  std::cout << "not-number\n";
}

void myFct() { }

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void myFct(T arg1, Ts... rest) {
    // is_arithmetic will derive either true_type or false_type
    do_stuff(arg1, std::is_arithmetic<T>{});
    myFct(rest...); // recurse
}
```

This is a typical pattern to get something like a "static if"

If I call this with `myFct(1, std::string{}, 2.0);` I get the output

```
number
not-number
number
```

Comment: Was a good idea. Will keep in mind those true_type and false_type. It might be useful someday. =D

Comment: the error messages from tag dispatch tend to be less insane than the ones from SFINAE also