# Array encapsulator that can work as fix-size (stack) AND dynamic-size (heap)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stack, heap-memory

Yesterday, I stumbled upon an library named Eigen, it provides [an array class](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html) that has signature like this:-

```
Array<float,Dynamic,1> b;//<--- dynamic = unknown at compile time
Array<float,3,1>       c;//<--- both row(=3) and col(=1) known at compile time
```

Here is the source code of [Array.h](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/Array_8h_source.html) and a closely related class [PlainObjectBase.h](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/PlainObjectBase_8h_source.html).

As far as I can guess (from digging), if both row and col are known at compile time, it will allocate memory as **stack variable**, same way as:-

```
float c[3];
```

I think it is very cool, because it can avoid unnecessary heap allocation.
It is very suitable in some situation.

### Question

What are the C++ technique/semantic to create collection that support both fix & dynamic size **within 1 class**?

What are the ideas behind it?
I am not asking for a full code or any snippet, but I don't mind it.

Answer can ignore all fact about how Eigen Array is implemented.  (Eigen is just an example.)

I want some solid idea to improve my own array encapsulator to be cool like that.

### My poor solution

- Create fields for both scenario (dynamic & fix), but in each scenario, use only some of them.
- Then, spam `std::enable_if` to control Dynamic vs Const, but I think it is anti-pattern.

Comment: It's a template class so you can use enable_if with is_arithmetic to make template specializations.  Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294267/class-template-for-numeric-types

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah  It is a very good link, thank.  It actually might be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do it with partial specialization.  Basically, the `Array` class template delegates creation of storage to another class template that is partially specialized on some magic value they've named `Dynamic`.

Here's a basic example:

```
#include <memory>

constexpr int Dynamic = -1;

template <typename T, int N>
struct Storage
{
    Storage() : data{} {}
    T data[N];
};

template <typename T>
struct Storage<T, Dynamic>
{
    Storage(int count) : data{new T[count]} {}
    Storage() = delete;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data;
};


template <typename T, int N>
struct Array
{
    Array() : storage{} {}
    Array(int count) : storage{count} {}
    Storage<T, N> storage;
};


int main() {
    Array<int, 4> a1;
    //Array<int, 4> a2(10);  // Error since base Storage template has no constructor taking int.
    Array<int, Dynamic> a3(10);
    //Array<int, Dynamic> a4{};  // Error since Storage<T, Dynamic> has its default constructor deleted.
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a4fafa266570e01)

Basically there are two different `Storage` templates, one that will be used when `N == Dynamic` and another that will be used for any other value.

In fact, if you look in [DenseStorage.h](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/5430cad5531274d51024d3950d2fa511aeec5055/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h) you'll see a similar pattern to my example.  There are a lot more specializations to support multiple dimensions and various differently-aligned data types, but it's the same concept.