# How to use concept to restrict typename to numeric? C++20 features

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, enable-if, concept

I am learning some modern C++20 features. One of them is concept. I have read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints and https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/defintion-of-concepts to get some examples to follow.

For now, I want to design a concept such that I can only accept numeric data type. In the traditional method, one can use

```
template<typename NumericType,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<NumericType>::value,NumericType>::type>
```

as suggested in [Class template for numeric types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294267/class-template-for-numeric-types/14294277?noredirect=1#comment118415886_14294277)

or one may also use `static_assert()` inside the definition of template class/function

```
static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<NumericType>::value, "NumericType must be numeric");
```

I am wondering what the syntax for concept should be? For now, I am doing

```
template<typename NumericType>
concept Numeric = std::is_arithmetic<NumericType>::value ;
```

and find that

```
template<Numeric T>
void f(T){}
```

can do the trick I expected (basically just duck typing). I am wondering am I correct or is there any difference?

Comment: not sure what the question is, but what you did is same what std concepts do, see for example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/floating_point (except they use _v instead of ::value to save typing)

Comment: std::floating_point doesn't quite do the trick. If you have integers mixed with floating point types, you may have issues. For example, check
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/659565761faf0dac

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
template <typename T>
concept NumericType= std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering am I correct or is there any difference?

You're correct.

Using [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) / [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to constrain templates has the same essential effect of concept-constrained templates.

SFINAE has additional (negative) side-effects (see WG21 P0225R0 [Why I want Concepts, and why I want them sooner rather than later](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0225r0.html)).

SFINAE is less a technology and more hack of C++. From this point of view the most important thing concepts can do is to be human readable!

Also take a look to: [Do C++20 Concepts replace other forms of constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76346085/3235496) for a borderline case.

> I am wondering what the syntax for concept should be?

Your syntax is right. Perhaps

```
template<class T> concept Numeric = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;
```

is a bit shorter.