# Do C++20 Concepts replace other forms of constraints?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, enable-if, void-t

C++20 has landed, bringing with it Concepts. If a project were to start now and target only C++20 and later standards, would it be appropriate to say previous forms of constraints are now superseded by Concepts and the `requires` clause?

Are there any cases where `enable_if` or `void_t` are still required, where Concepts cannot be made to replace them?

For example, `std::bit_cast` is constrained to require both `To` and `From` types to be of the same size and both types to be trivially copyable.

From cppreference:

> This overload participates in overload resolution only if sizeof(To) == sizeof(From) and both To and From are TriviallyCopyable types.

The MSVC standard library constrains this through an `enable_if_t` expression, while libcxx opts for a `requires` clause.

MSVC:

```cpp
enable_if_t<conjunction_v<bool_constant<sizeof(_To) == sizeof(_From)>, is_trivially_copyable<_To>, is_trivially_copyable<_From>>, int> = 0
```

libcxx:

```cpp
requires(sizeof(_ToType) == sizeof(_FromType) &&
         is_trivially_copyable_v<_ToType> &&
         is_trivially_copyable_v<_FromType>)
```

They perform the same logical operations through different language features.

To reiterate my question, are there any cases where this translation from one constraint method to another is not possible? I understand there are a lot of things Concepts and `requires` can do that `enable_if` and/or `void_t` can't, but can the same be said looking in the other direction? Would a wholly new codebase targeting C++20 and later ever need to fall back on these older language constructions?

Comment: It seems the Microsoft standard library implementation didn't use `requires` because they needed to support compilers that didn't implement C++20 concepts fully at the time. See https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/1749. I don't think there is any situation in which SFINAE with `enable_if`/`void_t` cannot be replaced by a `requires` clause on a fully conforming compiler.

Comment: *"I understand there are a lot of things Concepts and requires can do that enable_if and/or void_t can't"* - there supposed to be just one thing that Concepts and requires could do that older metaprogramming techniques could not, however it somehow got lost somewhere in standardization committee. So i think the better question would be "are there any cases where this translation from one constraint method to another make sense?". I'm not going to use concepts in project targeting C++20 at all.

Comment: So there are two questions here? Is there a reason to rewrite old code that works well? Perhaps not. Is there a reason to use old convoluted methods is new code, when there now is a dedicated way to express requirements? Not really (unless one of your compilers still has bugs).

Comment: This is going to be highly opinionated and based on my own experience, still it might provide some insight: I've been doing some extensive digging on this topic recently, and for most general cases, enable_if/void_t can be largely equivalent to concepts in terms of regular usage. As @BoP has written: migrating one way or another just to migrate seems unnecessary. However for some specific edge cases e.g. involving concept subsuming there might be discrepancies. But then, those discrepancies might probably affect even differently stated concepts that were designed to be equivalent.

Comment: Hopefully `concept` constrained templates should generate cleaner error diagnostics in future. This was 1 of the intentions behind the idea, but currently support for this feature is poor. With old `enable_if` hacks, there's no luck for good diagnostics. In new code, old methods just bring more irreadability. A demand for good diagnostics with `concept`s must become the focus of C++ community.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, sadly the old SFINAE is still necessary in some cases. The problem with `requires` (and constraints introduced by concepts) is them being checked **late**.

For example, consider [`std::make_[un]signed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned), which causes a hard error (aka is SFINAE-unfriendly) if given a non-integral type. You can't really stop that from happening with a `requires`/concept, because they would be checked after `make_[un]signed` is instantiated.

The code below fails with a hard error because of this: <kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:46,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:46,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:46,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:46,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cstd::signed_integral+T%3E%0Astd::make_unsigned_t%3CT%3E+to_unsigned(T+t)%0A%7B%0A++++return+t%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconcept+CanMakeUnsigned+%3D+requires(const+T+%26t)%7Bto_unsigned(t)%3B%7D%3B%0Astatic_assert(!!CanMakeUnsigned%3Cstd::string%3E)%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.22570909891783,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,overrides:!(),paneName:Clang,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:Clang,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.40234948604993,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+16.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:13,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,paneName:%27Clang+output%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Clang+output%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:53.59765051395007,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.77429090108217,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <concepts>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::signed_integral T>
std::make_unsigned_t<T> to_unsigned(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
concept CanMakeUnsigned = requires(const T &t){to_unsigned(t);};
static_assert(!CanMakeUnsigned<std::string>);
```

On the other hand, the ol' SFINAE is checked exactly in the order it appears in the source, so the version below does compile: <kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:46,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:46,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+std::enable_if_t%3Cstd::signed_integral%3CT%3E,+std::nullptr_t%3E+%3D+nullptr%3E%0Astd::make_unsigned_t%3CT%3E+to_unsigned(T+t)%0A%7B%0A++++return+t%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconcept+CanMakeUnsigned+%3D+requires(const+T+%26t)%7Bto_unsigned(t)%3B%7D%3B%0Astatic_assert(!!CanMakeUnsigned%3Cstd::string%3E)%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.22570909891783,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,overrides:!(),paneName:Clang,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:Clang,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.40234948604993,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+16.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:13,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,paneName:%27Clang+output%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Clang+output%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:53.59765051395007,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.77429090108217,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::signed_integral<T>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
std::make_unsigned_t<T> to_unsigned(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
concept CanMakeUnsigned = requires(const T &t){to_unsigned(t);};
static_assert(!CanMakeUnsigned<std::string>);
```

If you wanted to fix the code using only the modern `requires`/concepts, you'd have to wrap `std::make_unsigned` in something like this:

```
template <std::signed_integral T>
using CheckedMakeUnsigned = std::make_unsigned_t<T>;
```

AFAIK there isn't a way to do it that can be done locally when defined the function, you need a separate typedef (or the old SFINAE).

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say it's either a CWG defect, or a Clang bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such cases, and indeed you could directly copy the conjunction from the MSVC example into a `requires` clause, as you can do with any compile-time [boolean-testable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/boolean-testable) expression. Though ideally the requirements would be captured in an actual concept:

```
template<typename FromType, typename ToType>
concept bit_castable_to = requires (...);
```

which is easier to reuse and allows you to benefit from the more expressive syntax:

```
template<typename ToType, bit_castable_to<ToType> FromType>
// or
template<typename ToType>
ToType bit_cast(bit_castable_to<ToType> const auto& from);
```

This also improves the structure of the error output, which now directly mentions that your chosen types failed to satisfy the `bit_castable_to` concept, for example because `is_trivially_copyable` evaluated to false for your class Foo. However, a practical issue is that concepts can be composed of other concepts to arbitrary depths, so that the source of the failure can get buried under a long stream of messages.

Other than this simpler example, `enable_if` can be used to provide different implementations based on compile-time constraints, including different return types in the case of function overloads. This can also be done in a more readable fashion with some combination of concepts, `if constexpr` and `auto` return type deduction (which can also be constrained by a concept).

The main use of `void_t` I know of is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work), but this too can be expressed more elegantly using concepts, for example

```
template<typename Type>
concept has_member =
    requires (Type t) { t.member; };
// or
    requires { typename Type::member; };
```

You can also make this more specific:

```
template<typename Type>
concept has_int_member = 
    requires (Type t) { 
        { t.member } -> std::same_as<int&>;
    };
// or
    std::same_as<int, typename Type::member>;
```

I think this syntax is much easier on the eyes than the tangle of `decltype` and `std::declval` that was sometimes a necessary evil.

All in all, I see no reason to continue using `enable_if` or `void_t` contraption, unless required to support older compilers. I personally would be happy to never read or write one again. Concepts are just more expressive, and because it's very common for generic C++ code to have constraints, I think having an easy way of writing at least the syntactic ones as code is a great asset.