# Template that accepts only iterators pointing to arithmetic types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, sfinae

I'm trying to teach myself the SFINAE pattern and for a thing I'm writing I wanted to write a function that accepts `start`, `end` iterators to a value of an arithmetic type (e.g. for summing). This is what I came up with:

My `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "summer.hpp"


int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vec {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};  // these are OK
    auto sum = summer(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::string> vec2 {"a", "b"};  // these should be rejected
    auto sum2 = summer(vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
    std::cout << sum2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and then `summer.hpp`:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <
    typename Iter,
    typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<Iter>::value_type, Iter>,
    typename T = typename Iter::value_type
>
T summer(Iter start, Iter end)
{
    T sum{};
    for (auto it = start; it != end; it++)
    {
        sum += *it;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The SFINAE bit above I took from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294267/class-template-for-numeric-types/14294277) and just tweaked it to use the type trait that corresponds to the type an iterator points to (`value_type`). But I'm struggling to compile it, I'm getting a barrage of complaints about `value_type` being parsed as a non-type but yielding a type and hints that I should prefix it with adding `typename` (which is wrong):

```
$ g++ --std=c++17 main.cpp  && ./a.out 
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘summer(std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator)’
   10 |     auto sum = summer(vec.begin(), vec.end());
      |                                             ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:
summer.hpp:8:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class Iter, class, class T> T summer(Iter, Iter)’
    8 | T summer(Iter start, Iter end)
      |   ^~~~~~
summer.hpp:8:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
summer.hpp:5:5: error: dependent-name ‘std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value_type’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
    5 |     typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<Iter>::value_type, Iter>,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
summer.hpp:5:5: note: say ‘typename std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value_type’ if a type is meant
main.cpp:13:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘summer(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator)’
   13 |     auto sum2 = summer(vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
      |                                                ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:
summer.hpp:8:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class Iter, class, class T> T summer(Iter, Iter)’
    8 | T summer(Iter start, Iter end)
      |   ^~~~~~
summer.hpp:8:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
summer.hpp:5:5: error: dependent-name ‘std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value_type’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
    5 |     typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<Iter>::value_type, Iter>,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
summer.hpp:5:5: note: say ‘typename std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value_type’ if a type is meant
```

I believe I've put `typename` in the correct places, if I was to get rid of the arithmetic restrictions compiles just fine but then I don't want it to accept e.g. `string` vectors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There seems to be a note in there that tells you how to fix it.

Comment: Note that `Iter` might not always have a `::value_type` directly -- a pointer is an iterator, after all. What you actually want is `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type`. You also want to check that this value type is arithmetic, because currently you're checking to see if `Iter` itself is an arithmetic type.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Are you referring to `note: say ‘typename std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value_type’ if a type is meant`? That won't work, will it? That's supposed to return a `bool`, not a `typename`.

Comment: To satisfy my own curiosity: A [C++20 version](https://godbolt.org/z/joh9fWjc7) that uses concepts. Quite nifty.

Comment: @NathanPierson That looks cool, why not leave it as an answer?

Comment: Well, it's _not_ an answer--your question is how to get the SFINAE version working, and this is tangential to that.

Comment: I suppose my premise was to ultimately have a template that rejects certain specialisations and I used SFINAE to do it. Reading up on concepts, it seems they partially exist as a more elegant way to do what SFINAE does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, where do I start...

- `typename std::enable_if_t<...>` is wrong, remove `typename`. You only need it if there is `::` to the right of the template parameter, e.g. in `typename std::enable_if<...Iter...>::type`.
- `::value_type` is misplaced, it must be right after `Iter`.
- `...::value_type` needs `typename`.
- `std::is_arithmetic<...>` must be `std::is_arithmetic_v<...>` OR `std::is_arithmetic<...>::value`
- The second template argument in `std::enable_if_t` doesn't matter in this case, and can be removed.

So we end up with this code, which at least works:

```
template <
    typename Iter,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<typename Iter::value_type>>,
    typename T = typename Iter::value_type
>
```

But wait, there is more:

- `typename T = typename Iter::value_type` is a misuse of a template parameter, and can be broken by specifying a custom template argument.
- `typename = std::enable_if_t<...>` is a weak SFINAE, since the user can circumvent it by providing any template argument. Prefer this form: `std::enable_if_t<..., std::nullptr_t> = nullptr`, which doesn't have this problem.
- You should use `std::iterator_traits` instead of reading `::value_type` directly from the iterator, because some iterators (e.g. pointers) don't have it ([thanks  @NathanPierson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039832/template-that-accepts-only-iterators-pointing-to-arithmetic-types#comment120258427_68039832)).
- `auto it = start;` peforms an unnecessary copy. You can operate directly on `start`.

So the final version would look like this:

```
template <
    typename Iter,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type summer(Iter start, Iter end)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type sum{};
    for (; start != end; start++)
        sum += *start;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: An alternate to the non-type template parameter would be to make the return type of `summer` an `std::enable_if_t<...>`. Although probably with a `using` statement earlier to avoid making the repetitions of `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type` too unwieldy.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, especially the second portion of it since I don't think I would have picked up on those nuances by just following the docs, your first and second bullet points in particular, can you please point me to a resource on them (as in why they work or don't)?

Comment: @Nobilis First and second bullets in the first part of the answer, or in the second one?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry, in the second part, specifically why it's a misuse of a template parameter and also why it's a weak pattern, I think I saw both of those in the docs or at least well voted answers on SO (but perhaps out of date?).

Comment: @Nobilis There isn't much more to explain than what I already did, so I don't have any links. If user calls your function while explicitly specifying all 3 template arguments, `T` might be a wrong type, and SFINAE in the default argument of the 2nd parameter will be ignored completely. The latter is solved by moving SFINAE from default arg into the parameter type, which isn't ignored in that scenario.

Comment: I'm using `std::nullptr_t` as the type, since there's only one possible value for it, so the user can't generate unnecessary instantiations of your function (duplicating static variables in it, etc) by passing different arguments it.

Comment: @Nobilis Your code provides _default values_ for the second and third template parameters, but there's nothing stopping someone from calling it with non-default values. So `summer<std::string, void, std::string>( ... )` would still compile, because by providing your own values for the template arguments you're bypassing the SFINAE.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, I see, I didn't realise in `enable_if`, the second parameter is redundant in this case, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix `std::is_arithmetic<...>::value_type` with `typename` since `...` depends on another template argument.  Just like you did with `typename Iter::value_type`. See [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/)

That being said, you are applying the `std::is_arithmetic` check (why not `std::is_arithmetic_v`?) on the `Iter`ator itself, not on the type that the `Iter`ator refers to when dereferenced.

You could simply use `typename Iter::value_type` inside of `std::is_arithmetic`, eg:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<
  typename Iter,
  typename T = std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_arithmetic_v<typename Iter::value_type>,
    typename Iter::value_type
  >
>
T summer(Iter start, Iter end)
{
    T sum{};
    for (auto it = start; it != end; it++)
    {
        sum += *it;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This will work only for iterator types that define a `value_type` member (like `std::vector` iterators do), but it will not work on plain vanilla pointers instead, which are also valid iterators.  To work around that, you can use [`std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<
  typename Iter,
  typename T = std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_arithmetic_v<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>,
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type
  >
>
T summer(Iter start, Iter end)
{
    T sum{};
    for (auto it = start; it != end; it++)
    {
        sum += *it;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/7I8giL)

On a side note, your function is largely redundant, since the standard library has a [`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) function that performs the exact same summing action that you are, just without the SFINAE type check as it works on any type that defines an `operator+` (which `std::string` does), eg:

```cpp
std::vector<double> vec {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};  // these are OK
auto sum = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);
std::cout << sum << std::endl;

std::vector<std::string> vec2 {"a", "b"};  // these are also OK
auto sum2 = std::accumulate(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), "");
std::cout << sum2 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, just a quick question, I thought for `enable_if`, the first argument is supposed to return a `bool`, I did try prefixing `std::is_arithmetic` with `typename` but it won't compile as it complains about a type/value mismatch (expected `bool`, got `typename`). Is it supposed to go somewhere else?

Comment: The `accumulate` point is totally fair, this was just a contrived example that I came up with to easily demonstrate my issue.

Comment: ah, I think I see what you mean, please ignore my first comment

Comment: Oh, and your point about not using `is_arithmetic_v`, that's an alias for `::value` whereas I thought I need to use `::value_type` so I assumed it's just not correct.