# How to make `enable_if` a hard requirement

Tags: c++, templates, type-safety, type-level-computation

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14294277/3777717) contains the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<
    typename T, //real type
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type
> struct S{};

int main() {
   S<int> s; //compiles
   S<char*> s; //doesn't compile
}
```

The requirement that `T` satisfy `is_arithmetic` can easily be defeated, though, by specifying an arbitrary second type argument for the template `S`, e.g. `S<char*, void>`. Is there a way to foreclose this possibility?

Comment: Could defining a concept encapsulating `is_arithmentic` and using it with `requires` be the answer?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve, or is this academic?  With `template` specialization, one could just specialize `struct S<SomeArbitraryType>`, so how much effort are you willing to go through?

Comment: Change to `template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr> struct S{};`.

Comment: Or `std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr` to make sure that you can't specialize it for another value of the non-type template parameter

Comment: @StephenNewell, I'm actually writing code in which this question came up. What do you mean by "just specialize struct S<SomeArbitraryType>"? Can anybody do it without touching my code? Would it defeat anything (except `static_assert`), including what's suggested in my comment and songyuanyao's?

Comment: @songyuanyao, how does it work? What does the `*` change?

Comment: @ByteEater By using `enable_if` in the type of a non-type template parameter, it can't be bypassed like a default template argument.

Comment: @ByteEater Make the second parameter a non-type parameter. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74609155/12002570) which uses `template<typename T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type = 0> struct S{};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to foreclose this possibility?

Yes, there is as shown below. In particular, we can make the second parameter a non-type parameter with a default.

```
template<
    typename T,
    //make the second parameter a non-type parameter with default 
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, nullptr_t>::type N = nullptr 
> struct S{};

int main() {
   S<int> s; //compiles 
    //S<int, void> S2;  //DOESN'T COMPILE 
   //S<int, 1> S3;     //DOESN'T COMPILE
   
}
```

Comment: Observations: This requires `T` to be a valid non-type template parameter and constructible from `0` (which is fine for the specific case that `T` is supposed to be arithmetic, but not necessarily in general for conditions we might want to apply), and it opens up the possibility that people could do something silly with `S<int, 1>` instead of `S<int, 0>` as intended.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes the answer is specific for this question which uses `arithmetic`. Note also that we can disallow `S<int, 1>` by changing the above to `typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type N = 0, typename std::enable_if<N==0, T>::type = 0`. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qTf649shn). I've updated my answer showing the same.

Comment: Well, this is why I'd just use `std::nullptr_t` instead of `T` as the second argument to the `enable_if`. Because then there _aren't_ any other values besides `nullptr`, and you don't need to go "ah, but do I care about preventing `S<int, 0, 1>`"?

Comment: @NathanPierson Updated the answer to use `nullptr_t` as the second arg of `enable_if`.

Comment: @NathanPierson, @JasonLiam, is `typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, nullptr_t>::type N = nullptr` any different (except for omitting the name `N`, which I believe is optional) from `template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>` suggested in @songyuanyao's comment?

Comment: @ByteEater They have the same overall effect(except ofcourse in latter `N` is of type `T*` while in former `N` is of type `nullptr_t`).

Answer (score 6):

> The requirement that T satisfy is_arithmetic can easily be defeated

I mean, it is SFINAE, aka substitution is not an error. If you want to force specific types in templates, you can use concepts in c++20, or in c++17 - c++11, you have `static_assert`:

```
template<
    typename T //real type
> struct S{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, "T must be arithmetic");
};
```

There is no *defeating* that.

Answer (score 5):

Use concept will be much easier (since you have mentioned),

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept Arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;

template<Arithmetic T> struct S{};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fa17e637v)